# Youtube Data API quota exceeded

Tags: api, key, youtube-data-api

I am developing an app locally and I just integrated the Youtube data api v3 to query videos.

Last night I received the 403 error that said my daily quota has been exceeded. If I look at the chart under quotas in the developer console, it says there was 10,000 requests yesterday. This is totally impossible as I am only using this locally.

Here is the quota chart
[image]

If I click on credentials in the left hand menu and select the API key page, it says only 309 requests for that API key in the last 30 days. That is the only API key I have activated. It can't be API theft, as it only says 309 requests for that key.

[image]

I am totally confused. What is happening here? Is there a way to see the IP address where these requests are originating from?

Comment: 1 request could have a quota cost of over a hundred. So it's not surprising for you to hit 10,000 with 300 requests.

Use the quota calculator to get an estimate cost of each request.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. That is really low. I can only send 100 search queries a day? That is totally impractical to use on an app. Is their another service people use to search? I have one search query on each page. That is only 100 page requests. Pretty easy to exceed that.

Answer (score 8):

Those 2 stats are different from each other. 1 request could have a quota cost of one to over a hundred. That quota cost reflects to the queries per day stat. So it's not surprising for you to hit 10,000 with 300 requests.

To get around this issue, you may need to optimize your API request to retrieve only the resource that you need. If the default quota (10,000) isn't really enough, then you probably need to request for quota increase through the console or through this direct [apply for higher quota](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd5HxReFtxATJLNfLwQiucfQwYL295Xemgc6nhFXo1vcitg3A/viewform) link.

Complete info can be found in the [youtube documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#intro)

Answer (score 3):

You can check how to calculate on [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost)